# Recursive method to count figures in a number with boolean as return

Tags: java, recursion, boolean, counter

I recently has a test in university and I was struggling with a problem. The task was defined very specifically as following:

*Write a recursive method (don't change the signature, or parameters; no global variables allowed; don't use Strings or the method Stringbuffer; no loops) which returns "true" if the number of zeros in number "n" is odd and "false" if the number of zeros is even.*

Signature and Parameter:

```
public static boolean oddZeros(int n) {
}
```

So for:

```
n = 10 //true
n = 100 //false
n = 1402050 //true
n = 0 // true
n = 12 // false
```

you get the idea..

I understand the concept of recursion but i fail to see how i can count something, given only booleans. I tried adding a counter variable inside the method but whenever i make a recursive call, obviously the variable would be reset to its initialization.

Since this is a very specific problem, i didn't find any solutions so far. How would a method like this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static boolean oddZeroes(int n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return n == 0;
  }
  return (n % 10 == 0) ^ oddZeroes(n / 10);
}
```

You can even make it one-liner:

```
public static boolean oddZeroes(int n) {
  return n < 10 ? n == 0 : (n % 10 == 0) ^ oddZeroes(n / 10);
}
```

And if you want to process negative inputs as well, add something like `if (n < 0) {return oddZeroes(-n);}` in the beginning, i.e.:

```
public static boolean oddZeroes(int n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return oddZeroes(-n);
  }
  if (n < 10) {
    return n == 0;
  }
  return (n % 10 == 0) ^ oddZeroes(n / 10);
}
```

Comment: @ViktorMellgren Yeah, thanks for the comment! I'll add a notice about negative inputs, good catch :)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, i did not think of using bitwise operators!

Comment: @CoffeeKid you're welcome! Boolean ^ operator is basically adding modulo 2, i.e. if you think of true as 1 and false as 0, `1 ^ 1 = (1 + 1) % 2 = 0`, `1 ^ 0 = (1 + 0) % 2`, etc. So it often comes up in problems involving booleans and parity, like this one.

Comment: Not as easy to read as the other answer, but I like it, basically a map and fold/reduce.

Comment: @sbeliakov wow now that i looked closer into your solution and looked up how bitwise operators behave with booleans i feel really stupid i couldn't solve this task.. it is actually so simple :( well i guess at least i learned something new !

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to count anything.

You only have to observe that:

1. if you remove a `0` digit from a number that has an odd number of zeroes, the resulting (smaller) number does not have an odd number of zeroes.
2. if you remove a non `0` digit from a number that has an odd number of zeroes, the resulting (smaller) number also has an odd number of zeroes.

Finally, as the base of the recursion, if 0 < number < 10, it has an even number of `0`s (`0` `0`s), so your method should return `false`.

You can write a shorter implementation, but I preferred readability:

```
public static boolean oddZeros(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
         return true;
    else if (n < 10)
        return false;
    else if (oddZeros (n / 10)) {
        return n % 10 != 0; // removed digit is not 0
    } else {
        return n % 10 == 0; // removed digit is 0
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This assumes the input is non-negative. If you need to support negative input, you can add an initial condition of:

```
if (n < 0) {
    return oddZeros (-n);
}
```

Comment: `if (n < 10)` doesn't correctly handle the case of 0 which should return true.

Comment: Okay so this works as intended, thanks for the answer :) but what i don't understand is, how does `else if (oddZeroes (n / 10))` work? This sounds more like a command than a condition so how does this exactly work?

Comment: @ViktorMellgren I assumed non-negative input. A minor adjustment would be required to support negative inputs.

Comment: yes, simplest would probably be something like `if(n<0) oddZeroes(-n)`

Comment: @ViktorMellgren while that is true, i forgot to mention that the assumption in this task is n >= 0.

Comment: @Eran could you please explan how the line `else if (oddZeroes(n / 10) {` works? why does the program enter this if condition? I dont get it :(

Comment: @CoffeeKid `oddZeroes(n / 10)` returns true if the number that you get by removing the least significant digit from n has an odd number of 0s. If it does, then n has an odd number of 0s only if the removed digit (n % 10) is not 0.

Comment: @Eran okay im starting to understand the program now, thank you very much again for your help!!